# PHP program does not display mysqli queries properly

Tags: php, mysqli, utf-8

I am using MySQL Workbench, my database is set to UTF-8 ("utf8 - utf8_unicode_ci"), inside it characters display correctly, so does the website (i use this tag; `<meta charset="UTF-8">` ) displays them correctly. When I hardcode it to the HTML or when I echo it in php there is no issue.

When I query it in the database the special characters appear differently. For example, Workbench shows "geçmiş" and query that I send with mysqli returns "ge�mi?" on the page.

mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8mb4'); solved my problem.